# Load browserify boundle.js with require.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, browserify

we having framework that work with require.js
we are loading packages like following

```
define(["converter/service/utils"], function (utils) {
```

And now we are able to use utils file.

Now we have a new js file which was browserify and uglify like

```
browserify main.js | uglifyjs > bundle.js
```

i've add the boundle.js file to my project (under service folder) and I want to load it but it's not working...

I try to load it like following:

```
   define(["converter/service/bundle"], function (bundle) {
```

but bundle is empty (while debug it...)

Any idea how to load browserfiy file with require.js?

I know that in the doc of broswerify we should add it like

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

but **we use require.js** to load modules and I was able to do so with other js files...
for example if I save this file in my project

https://rawgit.com/hugeen/lebab-experiment/master/lebab.js

I can load it with require.js ...

***Edit:***

what I did is `npm init` &

```
npm install lebab --save
```

create file `main.js` and put the following code

```
var lebab = require("lebab");
```

And run the command

```
browserify --standalone someName main.js | uglifyjs > bundle.js
```

it finish sucessfully

Take the `bundle.js` file put it under `converter/service` folder

And try to require it like following:

```
define(["converter/service/bundle"], function (bundle) {
```

or also

```
define(["converter/service/someName"], function (bundle) {
```

and it doesn't work...what am I missing here?

**EDIT2**

Since we use our tool (which wrap require.js) it's hard to track the right error, there is some tool (require.js) which I use to verify it 
with webstoram vscode with some project adjustments. I just want to verify that the bundle was created right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bundle does not contain the necessary code to allow RequireJS to load it, because by default `browserify` does not include that is needed. One way to get the result you want is to use `--standalone` to tell Browserify to put a [UMD wrapper](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) around your bundle:

```
browserify --standalone someName main.js | uglifyjs > bundle.js
```

`someName` is a name that will be used by the UMD wrapper if it detects that it is not running in a CommonJS or AMD environment. In such case it will export your bundle as the symbol `someName` in the global space. You have to decide what name you want to use there.

With the UMD wrapper in place, your bundle will detect that it is running in an AMD environment (because RequireJS makes `define` available), and will call `define` to register itself with RequireJS as a module.

Comment: Hi Louis, I did it as you write (with standalone and someName ...)but when I try to use it I got errors: what I try now is:  define(["converter/service/bundle"], function (bundle) {   .... and also  define(["converter/service/someName"], function (bundle) { and it doesnt work, any idea what I miss here ?How should I load the file ? I put the new file under converter/serivce ....

Comment: please see my edit, I explained exactly what I did after your suggestion.Thanks!

Comment: Using `converter/service/someName` in the dependency list you give to `define` definitely will not work because `someName` is used only for the branch of the UMD code that is taken only if you are not in a CommonJS or UMD environment. The name `someName` has no bearing on the AMD module name. I've seen your edit to your question now. You should define what "not work" means concretely. You get a 404? You get an error message? Something to expect to happen does not happen?

Comment: It's very hard to give the error since we get some "internal framework" code to cast the error ...but I try to dig it out. meanwhile there is some simple tool /way which I can use to simulate the file that was created with require.js? (I mean outside our framework )  just to eliminate our framework possible issue...Thanks!!!

Comment: I was able to load the module but I got an empty object, any idea? I opened new question since you are answer was helps:) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45277610/require-module-and-get-empty-object

Comment: Can you please give me some hint what can be the problem here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45277610/require-module-and-get-empty-object